# Este programa não funciona. Porém se eu der o scanf da variável ch antes do scanf das variáveis x e y, ele funciona. Alguem saberia me explicar porque

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int  x, y;

    printf("Digite o valor de x e y:");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    printf("Digite o valor de ch:");
    ch = getchar();

    switch (ch)
    {
        case '+':
        {
            int c = x + y;
            printf("Soma: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            int c = x - y;
            printf("Subtracao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
            int c = x * y;
            printf("Multiplicacao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
            int c = x / y;
            printf("Divisao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Leia o manual. `scanf()` retorna um `int`. Teste. É ingênuo seguir sem testar. O problema com o programa é que você precisa consumir o  `\n` que encerrou o primeiro `scanf()` e como não fez isso ele é usado para a segunda chamada a `scanf()`

Comment: Muito Obrigado arfneto, não entendi muito. Só sei que quando se coloca o "\n" depois do scanf, ele funciona, embora o printf que pede o valor de ch so aparece depois. Vou olhar o manual sim. É pq estou começando o C agora e sozinho...kkkkk

Comment: Se não aparecer um '\n` o `scanf()` não retorna. Depois de ler os dois números chame `fgetc(stdin)` para ler esse '\n' ANTES de tentar ler uma letrinha chamando `getchar()`

Comment: Só pra deixar claro (não sei se foi essa a confusão que vc fez), o `\n` que estamos falando é apenas uma notação: **é uma forma de representar um único caractere**, que é a quebra de linha (quando vc digita ENTER, este caractere é enviado juntamente com os dados que vc digitou antes do ENTER - ou seja, se digitar "ab" ENTER, são enviados 3 caracteres: o `a`, o `b` e a quebra de linha - que chamamos simplesmente de `\n`). Isso não quer dizer que vc tem que digitar explicitamente o caractere ``\`` seguido do caractere `n`.

Comment: De qualquer forma, o que acontece é que o `scanf` não consome o `\n`, ele só lê os números. Depois, o `getchar` consome o `\n`, por isso ele nem espera vc digitar nada. Já tem bastante coisa no site sobre isso, por exemplo [aqui](/q/111697/112052) e [aqui](/search?q=%5Bc%5D+limpar+buffer), e tem [esse link também](https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html), pra se aprofundar no assunto.

Answer (score -1):

Compare com algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;     
    int y = 0;

    printf("Digite os valores de x e y: ");
    int res = scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    if (res != 2) return - 1; // nao leu, cancela
    fgetc(stdin);

    printf("Digite o operador (+ - * /): ");
    int ch = getchar();

    switch (ch)
    {
        case '+':
        {
            int c = x + y;
            printf("Soma: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            int c = x - y;
            printf("Subtracao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
            int c = x * y;
            printf("Multiplicacao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
            int c = x / y;
            printf("Divisao: %d\n", c);
            break;
        }
    };  // switch()
    return 0;
}
```

Você precisa consumir o '\n' que encerrou a chamada a `scanf()` ou ele vai servir para alimentar o `getchar()` e nunca vai ler o operador...

Como está aprendendo se acostume a mostrar os valores que imagina ter lido.

Se tivesse mostrado o valor de `ch` em seu programa depois do `getchar()` teria visto que o valor era `10`, o valor do `\n`

Comment: Bom dia arfneto. Eu nao entendo o que vc quer dizer quando fala em consumir o '\n'          E no seu programa postado vc não utiizou o '\n' no scanf. Tô mais perdido que cego em tiroteiro...kkk.

Comment: :) Você está lendo ao contrário. O `scanf()` não utiliza um `\n`. O `\n` finaliza a execução de `scanf()` e a função retorna com o total de coisas de conseguiu ler. Leu o programa que te mostrei? E se você não ler esse `\n` de alguma forma ele vai ser enviado pro `getchar()` na linha seguinte. Foi o que eu te mostrei e expliquei.

Comment: Resolvido o problema. O meu programa do jeito que está, basta digitar o comando fflush(stdin);  depois do scanf das variáveis x e y, e não precisa fazer mais nada que ele executa...KKKKKK

Comment: Memso assim, obrigado pela atenççao

Comment: Eu te expliquei o que está errado. Te mostrei o exemplo. Te expliquei para mostrar o valor lido pelo `getchar()`  e ver que é 10. E te expliquei que `fflush()` nem está definida para a entrada, apenas para a saída. Um ou outro compilador pode aceitar, mas não é assim que funciona. continua errado. O `scanf()` só  vai retornar depois de alguém teclar ENTER.  E aí ele pode retornar por exemplo `0` se você teclar apenas `x` na entrada. Rode o exemplo

Comment: Vixe. Vou me ligar nisso aí. Valeu e mais uma vez obrigado..